# Can we say that $V \cong V^*$ is not natural?

Tags: category-theory

Can we say that an isomorphism $V \cong V^*$ is not natural? It seems so intuitively, but formally the notion of a natural transformation between a functor and a cofunctor is not defined (or is it?).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed, a natural transformation is defined for two parallel functors, that is, functors with the same domain and codomain. The identity functor I and the single dual functor * are not parallel:

$I:\sf{Vect_K}\to \sf{Vect_K} $
$*:\sf{Vect_K}^{op}\to \sf{Vect_K} $

In other words: I is covariant and * is contravariant.

But let's ignore that. Suppose we have a collection of linear isomorphisms 
$\{a_V:V\to V^*\}_{V\in\sf{Vect_K}}.$

The naturality square would read

$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
& V & \longrightarrow^{a_V} & V^* & \\
L & \downarrow & & \uparrow & L^*\\
& W & \longrightarrow^{a_W} & W^* &

\end{array}$

where L* is the usual dual (precomposition) linear map defined by

$L^*f := [v\mapsto f(Lv)]=f\circ L,\ \ \ \ \ f\in W^*$

Now this diagram commutes iff

$\alpha_V = L^*\alpha_W L$

for *all* linear maps $L:V\to W$. But this cannot be since $\alpha_V$ is an isomorphism, and L not necessarily, e.g. take L=0.

[PS: I copied this answer from my answer [at physicsforums](http://www.physicsforums.com/showpost.php?p=2846497&postcount=9) ]

Answer (score 19):

This is more of a long comment on wildildildlife's answer. A natural question after reading that proof is: what happens if we restrict to the *groupoid* of finite dimensional vector spaces and their isomorphisms? (It may seem that picking $L=0$ is a bit of a "cheat".) The fact is that there is still no equivalence between the identity and the dual functor. The point is that the collection of isomorphisms $\{\alpha_V \colon V \to V^\ast \}$ is *only* allowed to depend on $V$, i.e. there must be a specific morphism for every $V$ that makes every diagram you can cook up using your category commutative.

In particular we can look at diagrams of the form

$
\begin{array}{ccc}
 V & \longrightarrow^{\alpha_V} & V^*  \\
 \downarrow & & \uparrow  \\
 V & \longrightarrow^{\alpha_V} & V^*. 
\end{array}$

Now we get $\alpha_V = A^\ast \alpha_V A$ for all $A \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$. Equivalently, if we use $\alpha_V$ to identify two bases of $V$ and $V^\ast$, we must have $\mathrm{id}_V = A^T A$ for all $A \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$, which is absurd.

This point of view also leads directly to what condition we need to impose on the category for the existence of an equivalence like this: we need to find a category of vector spaces where the automorphisms $A \colon V \to V$ are the orthogonal matrices (wrt a basis). The most natural thing to consider is then finite dimensional spaces equipped with an inner product<sup>1</sup> and morphisms preserving the inner product. Hence we have rediscovered the principle that you can identify a vector space with its dual precisely when it has an inner product.

<sup>1</sup> Remark: By an inner product I really mean an arbitrary nondegenerate bilinear form, so over $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$ this is non-standard usage. Note that this category is automatically a groupoid, since any map of vector spaces preserving the inner product is an isomorphism.

Comment: Interesting answer/comment!

Comment: This is great stuff 8)

Comment: @Alexei, wildildildlife: thanks! On an unrelated note, what's up with the extra "ild"?

Comment: I am sorry, but what is an "ild"?

Comment: Ild as in wild_ildild_life ;)

Comment: I mean that you're named after the band Wildildlife and your icon is the album cover for "Six". I was just curious why you put in one more "ild" in the name.

Comment: Ah! Well, I like the band and their name, but I wanted a nonexisting name; as they already added an _ild_ to 'wildlife', I thought I'd do the same.