# Ring of formal power series finitely generated as algebra?

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series

I'm asked if the ring of formal power series is finitely generated as a $K$-algebra. Intuition says no, but I don't know where to start. Any hint or suggestion?

Comment: You mean **formal power series**?

Comment: Try to write $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ as a finite linear combination?

Comment: @HuiYu yes, you can write it as $1\times (1+x+x^2+...)$.

Comment: formal series, right sorry

Comment: If $K$ is a field, then show that $K[[x]]$ has uncountable dimension as a $K$-vector space, while any finitely-generated $K$-algebra has at most countable dimension.

Comment: By looking at the degree, you see the only possible generator is $x$. But it does not generate the algebra.

Comment: @Hui Yu: Are you sure that this sketch of proof works? For example, what is the degree of a formal power series?

Answer (score 10):

Let $A$ be a non-trivial commutative ring. Then $A[[x]]$ is not finitely generated as a $A$-algebra.

Indeed, observe that $A$ must have a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, so we have a field $k = A / \mathfrak{m}$, and if $k[[x]]$ is not finitely-generated as a $k$-algebra, then $A[[x]]$ cannot be finitely-generated as an $A$-algebra. So it suffices to prove that $k[[x]]$ is not finitely generated. Now, it is a straightforward matter to show that the polynomial ring $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ has a countably infinite basis as a $k$-vector space, so any finitely-generated $k$-algebra must have an at most countable basis as a $k$-vector space.

However, $k[[x]]$ has an uncountable basis as a $k$-vector space. Observe that $k[[x]]$ is obviously isomorphic to $k^\mathbb{N}$, the space of all $\mathbb{N}$-indexed sequences of elements of $k$, as $k$-vector spaces. But it is well-known that $k^\mathbb{N}$ is of uncountable dimension: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176475/what-is-the-standard-proof-that-dimk-mathbb-n-is-uncountable), for example.

Comment: This is a nice answer. However, a subalgebra of A[[x]] can be finitely generated. Am I right ?

Answer (score 6):

Finitely generated $k$-algebras are [Jacobson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring), hence finitely generated local $k$-algebras are artinian, hence finitely generated local $k$-domains are fields. Well, $k[[x]]$ is not a field.

Comment: Dear @Martin, This is really nice!

Comment: I don't understand your claim that finitely-generated local $k$-algebras are artinian, but it's certainly true that a local Jacobson domain must be a field. (Because then the unique maximal ideal = Jacobson radical = nilradical = 0.)

Comment: In a local jacobson ring, there is only one prime ideal, and artinian = noetherian + zero-dimensional.

Comment: Basically I use the same argument which you suggest.