# tensor product of infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V,W$ be vector space over field $k$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
V^*\otimes W &=&V^*(\oplus_{i\in I} k_i)\\
&=&\oplus_{i\in I}(V^*\otimes k_i)\\
&=& \oplus_{i\in I}V^*_i\\
&=& \oplus_{i\in I}Hom(V,k)_i,
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
Hom(V,W)=Hom(V,\oplus_{i\in I}k_i).
\end{eqnarray*}
When $W$ is finite dimensional, we have $Hom(V,\oplus_{i\in I}k_i)=\oplus_{i\in I}Hom(V,k)_i$. Thus $V^*\otimes W=Hom(V,W)$.

Does the equality holds when $W$ is infinite dimensional and $V$ finite dimensional? Is the equality holds when $W$ is infinite dimensional and $V$ also infinite dimensional?

I am confused. By universal property I only obtain $
Hom(M,\Pi_{i\in I}N_i)=\Pi_{i\in I}Hom(M,N_i)$. Can we obtain $Hom(M,\oplus_{i\in I}N_i)=\oplus_{i\in I}Hom(M,N_i)$ in general?

Thanks.

Comment: To sum up, if both are infinite dimensional, the result is wrong. Otherwise it will be true. See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679584/why-is-texthomv-w-the-same-thing-as-v-otimes-w/679600#679600).

Comment: How to prove if $V$ is finite dimensional but $W$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: It's explained in the first question I linked -- the canonical morphism $V^* \otimes W \to \hom(V,W)$ is an isomorphism in this case, because every linear map $V \to W$ has finite dimensional range.