# Extension of representations and first cohomology

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a profinite group and $k$ a field. For any finite dimensional $k$-representation $V$ of $G$, we denote its dual by $V^*$. I found the statement saying that there is an ismorphism

$\mathrm{Ext}^1(V_1,V_2)\simeq H^1(G,V_1^*\otimes V_2)$

where $V_i$ are finite dimensional $k$-representations of $G$. Could I get a reference for this isomorphism? - I am wondering how the explicit map goes.

Comment: You can find this in the book by Cartan-Eilenberg. The isomorphism is completely explicit at the level of chain  complexes.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am really sorry, but at the moment I have no access to that book. If possible, could you give some explanation?

Comment: Using [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988633), one has a functorial isomorphism $X \otimes_k Y^* \cong \mathrm{Hom}_F(Y, X)$, where $Y^* = \mathrm{Hom}_k(Y,k)$. 

When $X, Y$ are finite dimensional representations of $G$ over $k$, this corestricts to a functorial isomorphism 
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_{k[G]}(k, X \otimes_k Y^*) = (X \otimes_k Y^*)^G \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{k[G]}(Y, X)$$

Taking the first derived functor should give you
$$H^1(G, X \otimes_k Y^*) = \mathrm{Ext}^1_{k[G]}(k, X \otimes_k Y^*) \cong \mathrm{Ext}^1_{k[G]}(Y,X) $$
as desired.

Comment: Notice that in an abelian category $\mathscr A$, like $\mathsf{Mod}_{k[G]}$, the abelian group $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathscr A}(Y,X)$ classifies extensions (short exact sequences) of the form $$ 0 \to X \to E \to Y \to 0. $$ (Be careful about the position of $X$ and $Y$ !)