# Do canonical isomorphisms involving the tensor product and dual spaces still hold for arbitrary modules?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

For vector spaces $V, W$ we have the following canonical isomorphisms, where $V^*$ denotes the dual space of $V$:
$$(V\otimes W)^*\cong V^*\otimes W^*$$
$$V^*\otimes W\cong \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)$$
Do these still hold true for modules $V, W$ over a commutative ring $A$?

I'm going to take a guess and say that the answer is probably yes, but apart from the case that $V, W$ are free, I was unable to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it does not always hold that $V^*\otimes W\cong \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)$, even for vector spaces! [See this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/573416/81360) for details. One general version of this that does hold in general is the [tensor-hom adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction)
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(V\otimes W,X)\;\cong\;\mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathrm{Hom}(W,X)).
$$
This general fact gives us an interest result regarding $(V \otimes W)^*$. Letting $X$ be the base ring $R$ yields
$$
(V \otimes W)^* = \mathrm{Hom}(V \otimes W,R) \cong
\mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathrm{Hom}(W,R)) = \mathrm{Hom}(V,W^*).
$$
From the first statement, we see that it does not necessarily hold that $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W^*) \cong V^* \otimes W^*$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! I saw these two isomorphisms in a linear algebra textbook and overlooked the finiteness assumption. The adjunction between tensor and hom is more or less just a restatement of the universal property of the tensor product, right?

Comment: @mxian yes, it's a restatement of the universal property of the tensor product. This is due to the fact that homomorphisms $V \to \operatorname{Hom}(W,X)$ are naturally isomorphic to bilinear maps $V\times W\to X$.

Comment: @Lukas That comment actually made a few things click for me, thank you. So the isomorphism from $V\times W \to X$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathrm{Hom}(W,X))$ should be the Currying map, is that right?

Comment: @BenGrossmann exactly, it‘s the Currying map.