# complex valued real-linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $V^{*}$ denote its dual space.  Why is $V^* \otimes \mathbb{C}$ the space of complex-valued real-linear functionals on $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $V^\ast \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is not *equal* to the space of complex valued real linear functionals, however in finite dimensions they are canonically isomorphic. One way to think of the space of complex valued real linear functionals on $V$ is to regard it as $Hom(V,\mathbb{C})$. Here I mean to regard $\mathbb{C}$ as a 2-dimensional real vector space and think of homomorphisms of real vector spaces.

In the setting where the vector spaces are finite dimensional we have a canonical isomorphism $Hom(V,W)\cong V^\ast\otimes W$ and the answer to your question is just a specific instance of this isomorphism. In case you are unfamiliar, the isomorphism from $V^\ast\otimes W$ is given by $(\phi\otimes w)(v)=\phi(v)w$.

In the infinite dimensional setting the answer appears to be more subtle, as is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573378/u-otimes-v-versus-lu-v-for-infinite-dimensional-spaces).