# Dimensions of Direct Sum vs Direct Product

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that, if $A$ is an infinite set and $F$ is a field, then the direct sum of copies of $F$ indexed by $A$ has strictly lower dimension than the corresponding direct product.

I know that if I can show that $A^k$, for any positive integer $k$, has the same cardinality as $A$, and if I can also show that $card(A)card(F)<card(F)^{card(A)}$, I'll be one, but how exactly do I do this?

Comment: It's not true, the cardinalities can be equal $$\operatorname{card} \left(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\right) = \left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = \operatorname{card} \bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem was asking about the dimensions, not cardinalities, of the vector spaces.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551/dimension-of-infinite-product-of-vector-spaces

Comment: Note that the direct product is in fact the dual space of the sum. Then read the wonderful answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/why-are-vector-spaces-not-isomorphic-to-their-duals).