# Cardinality of the set of all functions with finite support

Tags: linear-algebra, cardinals

Let F be a countable field and B an infinite set. Let $(F^B)_0$ be the set of all functions with finite support from F to B. Is it true that $|(F^B)_0|=|B|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the axiom of choice, yes.

To see this note that there is an injection from $B$ into $(F^B)_0$ in the obvious way; in the other direction $(F^B)_0$ is a subset (or rather, can be identified with a subset) of $(B\times F)^{<\omega}$, the set of all finite sequences from $B\times F$.

The cardinality of $(B\times F)^{<\omega}$ is $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}|B\times F|=|B|\cdot|F|\cdot\aleph_0$, but since $B$ is infinite, you get that this just equals $|B|$.

Comment: Asaf , I think that you use $|B\times F|^n=|B\times F|$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @AsafKaragila doesn't this prove that for $X,Y$ with $|X|\geq |Y|\geq 2$ and $X$ infinite, $|(Y^X)_0|=|X|$?

Comment: @Exterior: What if $X=\Bbb N$ and $Y=\Bbb R$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. Could you explain the cardinality argument in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-i)?

Comment: @Exterior: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/why-are-vector-spaces-not-isomorphic-to-their-duals for starters.

Comment: @AsafKaragila so we generally have $|M^\ast|=|k|^{\dim V}$, and in the infinite dimensional case we have $|V|=\max (|k|,\dim V)$. I am still confused at why we may conclude $\operatorname{card}V <\operatorname{card}V^\ast$ if we merely assume $\dim V \geq |k|$. If the assumption is actually a strict inequality, then I don't understand how knowing every field has a countable subfield helps.

Comment: @Exterior: It seems to me that you are asking a question which deserves a proper answer, and not in the comments. And since I'm going to bed, I will now leave you in the capable hands of the rest of the site. But you should write a question where you give a correct context (because frankly, I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to understand *exactly*), and explain what step you seem to be missing out on. And if you can do that, you'll surely receive a good answer from one person or another.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks. I asked my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534223/trying-to-understand-the-slick-proof-about-the-dual-space).