# Dimension of space of linear maps between infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and suppose $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $F$. What is the dimension (meaning cardinality of any basis) of the space of linear maps from $V$ to $W$? I hope there is an answer in terms of the dimension of $V$, the dimension of $W$, and the cardinality of $F$.

If $V$ is finite dimensional, the answer is the product of the dimension of $V$ and the dimension of $W$. [This recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150660/uncountable-linearly-independet-family-in-k-mathbbn/1150669#1150669) shows the dimension is at least continuum if $V$ has countably infinite dimension and $W=F$.

Comment: This, to some extent, has been answered in [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/why-are-vector-spaces-not-isomorphic-to-their-duals).