# Is ${\rm Hom}\left(\prod_{i\in{\cal I}}M_{i},N\right)\cong\bigoplus_{i\in{\cal I}}{\rm Hom}\left(M_{i},N\right)$ for modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $\left\{ M_{i}\right\} _{i\in{\cal I}}$ ,$N$ are $R$-modules. It is elementary that there is a natural module isomorphism
$${\rm Hom}\left(\bigoplus_{i\in{\cal I}}M_{i},N\right)\cong\prod_{i\in{\cal I}}{\rm Hom}\left(M_{i},N\right).$$
Is the dual statement also true? That is, do we also have the following isomorphism?
$${\rm Hom}\left(\prod_{i\in{\cal I}}M_{i},N\right)\cong\bigoplus_{i\in{\cal I}}{\rm Hom}\left(M_{i},N\right)?$$

It is worth mentioning the most famous example: in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936654/help-to-show-that-bigoplus-i-in-mathbbn-mathbbz-cong-operatornamehom?noredirect=1&lq=1), a positive answer is given in the special case of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$. But it seems pretty ad-hoc, and I suspect that this is not generalizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample which does not require the use of the axiom of choice. Setting $R = \mathbb{Z}$, let $M = \prod_p C_p$ be the product of the cyclic groups of prime order, and let $N = \prod_p C_p / \bigoplus_p C_p$ be the quotient of the direct product by the direct sum. The direct sum $\bigoplus_p C_p$ is in fact the torsion subgroup of $M$, so $N$ is the torsion-free quotient.

So $\text{Hom}(M, N)$ is nontrivial, since it contains at least the quotient map $M \to N$, but $\bigoplus_p \text{Hom}(C_p, N)$ is trivial, since $N$ is torsion-free.

Comment: $N$ is a funny little group, incidentally. Although it may not look like it, multiplication by $n$ is actually an isomorphism for all $n \neq 0$, so $N$ is actually a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Answer (score 0):

This should be false. For example, dimension-counting shows that $\hom_{\mathbb{R}}(\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})\not\cong\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\hom_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$.

The right-hand side has dimension $|\mathbb{N}|$, writing a basis vector for each $i$.

The left-hand side is too big. Even $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}$ by itself already has dimension $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|$ (See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551/dimension-of-infinite-product-of-vector-spaces) for example), and taking a dual $\hom(-,\mathbb{R})$ will only make it bigger.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150660/uncountable-linearly-independet-family-in-k-mathbbn) might be a nicer example of an uncountable linearly independent set for the left-hand side.

Comment: Note that this argument requires the axiom of choice (and there are other counterexamples which avoid this).