# Polar Decomposition: Ranges

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This is just a note.*

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$, $\mathcal{K}$.

Consider a closed operator:
$$A:\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{K}:\quad A=A^{**}$$

Construct its modulus:
$$|A|:=\sqrt{A^*A}:\quad|A|^*=|A|$$

Regard a decomposition:
$$A=J|A|:\quad JJ^*J=J$$

> Then for its kernel:
>   $$\mathcal{N}J=(\mathcal{R}|A|)^\perp\implies\mathcal{N}J=(\mathcal{R}A^*)^\perp$$

How can i check this?

*(The latter is better to work with.)*

Comment: Polar decompositions are not necessarily unique. You should state your particular definition.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Yep, I haven taken as granted that this is well-known. *(I just didn't want to spoil the thread with basics.)*

Comment: @T.A.E.: Remember there was a great answer on cardinality of  infinite Hamel dimension which got terribly spoiled by linear algebra lemmas.

Comment: But the result changes if you choose a different polar part.

Comment: @T.A.E.: True, so let me add canonical.

Comment: That's the point: there is no 'canonical'.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Oh hmm, I'm sorry then. What could happen?

Comment: @T.A.E.: But isn't it unique when requiring to act only the range of the modulus??

Comment: @T.A.E.: Besides I found this great answer given by Arturro Magadin which got spoiled: [Algebraic Dual](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/58598/79762)

Comment: $J$ is not uniquely defined on $\mathcal{R}(|T|)^{\perp}$ if this subspace is non-zero. Some people prefer minimal partial isometries, and others like full isometries. I think Rudin likes maximal.

Comment: @T.A.E.: I see your point. Let me think of a solution.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Ok I've changed "its polar" to "the polar" and specified its null space. Do you think it is ok this way?

Comment: @T.A.E.: Rudin, Functional Analysis?

Comment: I think that's okay. Yes, Rudin FA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

By square root lemma:
$$\|A\varphi\|=\||A|\varphi\|\implies\mathcal{N}A=\mathcal{N}|A|$$

Exploit selfadjointness:
$$\mathcal{N}J=(\mathcal{R}|A|)^\perp=\mathcal{N}|A|=\mathcal{N}A=(\mathcal{R}A^*)^\perp$$

Concluding the assertion.