# Polar Decomposition: Adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$.

Consider a closed operator:
$$A:\mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}:\quad A=A^{**}$$

Polar decompose:
$$A=J|A|:\quad J^*J=1_{\overline{\mathcal{R}|A|}}$$

Note that one has:
$$\overline{\mathcal{R}|A|}=\overline{\mathcal{R}A^*}\quad\overline{\mathcal{R}|A^*|}=\overline{\mathcal{R}A}$$

> Then identity holds:
>   $$|A^*|:=\sqrt{AA^*}=J|A|J^*$$
>
> Especially that gives:
>   $$A^*=|A|J^*=J^*|A^*|$$

How can I prove this?

**References**

For construction see [Square Root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/997186/79762)

For the relation see: [Ranges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1161941/79762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Finally I got it!! :D*

**Reducibility**

It acts on the range:
$$J^*J|A|=1_\overline{\mathcal{R}|A|}|A|=|A|$$

As it is bounded:
$$J^*J\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H}):\quad(J^*J|A|)^*=|A|J^*J$$

So one obtains:
$$|A|J^*J=(J^*J|A|)^*=|A|^*=|A|$$

Concluding reducibility.

**Positivity**

Regard the selfadjoint:
$$S:=J|A|J^*=(J|A|J^*)^*=S^*$$

Note that it is:
$$\mathcal{D}|A|\subseteq\mathcal{D}|A|^{1/2}:\quad|A|=|A|^{1/2}|A|^{1/2}$$

Numerical range:
$$\langle J|A|J^*\psi,\psi\rangle=\langle|A|^{1/2}J^*\psi|A|^{1/2}J^*\psi\rangle\geq0$$

But for selfadjoints:
$$S=S^*:\quad\langle\sigma(S)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(S)}$$

Concluding positivity.

**Identity**

As it is bounded:
$$J\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K}):\quad(J|A|)^*=|A|J^*$$

So one obtains:
$$|A^*|^2=AA^*=J|A|\cdot|A|J^*=J|A|J^*J|A|J^*=S^2$$

As both are positive:
$$|A^*|^2=S^2\implies|A^*|=S$$

Concluding identity.

**Relation**

As it is bounded:
$$J\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K}):\quad (J|A|)^*=|A|J^*$$

So one obtains:
$$A^*=|A|J^*=J^*J|A|J^*=J^*|A^*|$$

Concluding relation.