# Dimension of the dual of an infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

So it's a standard advanced-linear algebra fact that if $\dim V=\kappa\ge\infty$ then $\dim V^*=\kappa'>\kappa$, and this proof makes sense enough to me. What I'd be interested in showing or learning, is actually calculating $\kappa'$ as a cardinality, in terms of $\kappa$. Clearly it is just a function of $\kappa$ (doesn't depend on base field), and knowing just this restricted statement above says certain cardinalities can't arise as the dimensions of dual spaces.

For example, is $\dim k^{\mathbb{N}}$ equal to the cardinality of the continuum? Yes, and for $k=\mathbb{R}$ I think you can argue based on decimal expansions.

In general, I see that you can argue as follows: $\kappa'$ is the cardinality of a minimal set $S\subset\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ of subsets of $\kappa$ with the following property: every subset of $\kappa$ is a union of finitely many elements of $S$. I'd assume I could prove that minimality exists by Zorn, and that this finite union is unique by minimality (maybe this part isn't true?), but the goal again, is just expressing this cardinality $\kappa'$ in terms of $\kappa$. Any ideas?

Comment: [It's not a function of $\kappa$ only](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/why-are-vector-spaces-not-isomorphic-to-their-duals).

Comment: But is the dimension (cardinality of the Hamel basis) of $V^*$ a function of the dimension of $V$, independent of the field?

Comment: These old sci.math posts may be of use: [23 July 2000](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=252940) AND [24 July 2000](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=252942)

Comment: These all answer my question, thank's so much!

Comment: The links to my two July 2000 sci.math posts no longer work (or are behind a paywall). The following links to the google sci.math archive still work: [1st July 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/7ZsV3PKErFY/m/D48zJ_WTThwJ) *AND* [2nd July 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/7ZsV3PKErFY/m/B_lg-OOn9DwJ). The 2nd post corrects some oversights made in the first post.