# Dimension of $End (V)$, $V$ infinite dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, cardinals

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ such that its dimension over $\mathbb{F}$ is a cardinal $k$.

Is true that the dimension of $End(V)$ as $\mathbb{F}$ vector space is again $k$?

**EDIT**: egreg answer below proves that if $k \geq |\mathbb{F}|$ the statement is false. But what happens in other cases? In particular what if we set $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: OP asks for infinite dimensions. And yeah, the claim is correct.

Comment: Is $k$ the dimension of $V$ over $\mathbb K$ ?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58598/328173)

Comment: What's $\Bbb{K}$? Is it a typo for $\Bbb{F}$? If so, then the claim is false: e.g., take $\Bbb{F}$ to be any finite or countable field and take $k = \omega$. Then if $V$ is an $\Bbb{F}$-vector space of dimension $k$, $V$ is countable, but $\mbox{End}(V)$ is uncountable (since the uncountably many functions from $k$ to itself induce uncountably many distinct endomorphisms of $V$).

Comment: Sorry but I'm not talking of the cardinality of $End(V)$, I'm looking at its dimension as $\mathbb{F}$-vector space.

Comment: I should have explained that in my example, the cardinality of $\mbox{End}(V)$ is the same as its dimension. I see egreg has written this up as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a specific case, with $\mathbb{F}$ the rational field or a finite field. Then, for an infinite dimensional vector space $V$, we have
$$
\dim V=|V|
$$
because an element of $V$ is a finite linear combination of elements of a basis and the choice of the scalars is in a countable (or finite) set.

Note now that $\lvert\operatorname{End}(V)\rvert=|V^k|$, because any endomorphism of $V$ is defined by an arbitrary function from the basis to $V$. Thus
$$
\dim\operatorname{End}(V)=\lvert\operatorname{End}(V)\rvert=
k^k>k=\dim V
$$
The same can be said whenever $k\ge|\mathbb{F}|$.