# Is $\dim \mathcal{L}(V,W)\ge |F|$ for infinite dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

In Lemma 2 of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58598/577897), it was shown that if $\dim V$ was infinite, then $\dim V^*\ge |F|$. As $V^*=\mathcal{L}(V,F)$, this led me to wonder if the same held for the general space of linear transformations $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$.

More concretely, if either $\dim V$ or $\dim W$ is infinite, does $\dim \mathcal{L}(V,W)\ge |F|$?

As far as I can see, my conjecture holds at least for the case when $\dim V$ is infinite, if we modify the proof for $\dim V^*\ge |F|$ slightly, as follows $-$

Consider an arbitrary non-zero vector $v\in W$. If we re-define $\mathbf{f}_c$ as $\mathbf{f}_c\colon V\to W$, $\mathbf{f}_c(\epsilon_n) = c^n v$ if $n\in\omega$, and $\mathbf{f}_c(\epsilon_i)=0$ if $i\geq\omega$. Then as $\alpha_1\mathbf{f}_{c_1} + \cdots + \alpha_m\mathbf{f}_{c_m} = \mathbf{0}$ implies
\begin{align}
(\alpha_1 c_1^i + \cdots + \alpha_m c_m^i)v &= 0 \\
\implies \alpha_1 c_1^i + \cdots + \alpha_m c_m^i &= 0,
\end{align}

the rest of the proof should proceed just as it did for $\dim V^*\ge |F|$. However, I have not been able to see if my conjecture is valid when $\dim W$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\dim V$ is infinite and $W$ is not $0$, then by choosing a non-zero vector $x\in W$, you get an inclusion :
$$\mathcal L(V,F) \hookrightarrow \mathcal L(V,W)$$

Therefore, $\dim\mathcal L(V,W) \geq |F|$ by the lemma you cite.

If $\dim V= n$ is finite and $\dim W = \kappa$ is infinite, then :
$$\mathcal L(V,W) \simeq W^n$$
Therefore $\dim \mathcal L(V,W) = \kappa^n = \kappa$, which can be $<|F|$.  (For example if $F = \mathbb R$ and $\kappa = \aleph_0$)

Comment: How do you show that $\mathcal L(V,W) \simeq W^n$?

Comment: Choose a basis $(e_i)$ of $V$. A linear map $f\in\mathcal L(V,W)$ is uniquely defined by the $f(e_i)$.